# Flutter adaptive ListView height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a vertical ListView inside a Card inside a Row, next to another widget, which can have different heights. Now I would like the Card to stretch to fill all the space of the Row. Here is an example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        children: [
            Card(
                child: WidgetWithDynamicHeight(),
            ),
            Card(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListTile(items[index]),
                ),
            ),
        ]
    );
}
```

Now, I could wrap everything with a SizedBox and set a fixed height, but that is not what I want. I want the Row to be as big as the first Widget (`WidgetWithDynamicHeight`), and the second card to have the exact same size. How can I implement that?

Comment: What if you wrap both Cards in Expanded?

Comment: Does not work. In that case, Expanded would only set the width, not the height. The problem is, that the vertivcal ListView needs a fixed height.

Comment: Try to wrap `Row`with `IntrinsicHeight` widget

Answer (score 0):

Try Intrinsic height. It will build all children at the same height of the tallest child

```
return IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
        children: [
            Card(
                child: WidgetWithDynamicHeight(),
            ),
            Card(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListTile(items[index]),
                ),
            ),
        ]
    )
);
```

More about [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)